# Convert rem to px without reflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some constant in `rem`s, but `rem` itself isn't a constant (depends on media queries and `vmin`). For some perpoise I need this value in `px`.

Of course I can create a temporary div, set its size to that value in `rem` and `getComputedStyle` of it to get value in `px`. But I'd like to do that without causing a reflow by reading the computed style.

Comment: You need to be more clear. From your comments, I believe you are saying that the value of some of your child elements changes based on media queries and vmin. Not that rem, the root em, itself changes which isn't true.

Comment: @Rob, no `rem` itself depends on media queries and vmin. But there are other changes and I don't want to force recalculation between them.

Comment: Again, either you aren't being clear on how this rem value is being changed or you don't understand how rem is calculated. Are you changing the font size on the `<html>` element in some way?

Comment: @Rob `@media (...) { html { font-size: ...vmin; } }`.

Answer (score 12):

A `rem` unit equal to the computed value of ‘font-size’ on the root element. (https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#font-relative-lengths)

You can get that easily enough with 1 rem =

```
parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize))
```

Comment: Why do you think, it wouldn't cause a reflow?

Comment: I know getComputedStyle() has been said to cause reflow. Are you sure that's still true? Profiling in Safari and Chrome give no indication of style recalculations or window repainting when the function being called.

Comment: Reflow is caused only if you have other dom or style changes and call getComputedStyle after that. Otherwice there is nothing to recalculate, so reflow doesn't occur.

Comment: Again, I'll ask: are you sure? Testing it with a style change followed by a timeout calling `getComputedStyle`, doesn't show a second redraw or recalculate in either chrome or safari.

Comment: why not document.body.style.fontSize ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition rem is

*[Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element.

  When specified on the font-size property of the root element,

the rem units refer to the property’s initial value.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#font-relative-lengths)*

So you should be able to get it's size with:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)['font-size']
```

Comment: Why do you think, it wouldn't cause a reflow?