# CSS Converting Px Units to Rem/Em?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Before I learned about rem/em units, I coded my entire website using px so it's not very responsive.

Is there a way to convert px to rem/em units so changing my website will be faster and easier?

Comment: Related: [Convert rem to px without reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001097/convert-rem-to-px-without-reflow).

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `px` value to `rem` you have to set a `font-size` on `<html>` element.

```
html {
  font-size: 16px
}
```

Then, you can use the formula and manually compute its rem equivalent.

EM to PX Formula:

```
rem = px / base font
```

```js
function convert() {
  const baseFont = parseInt(document.querySelector("#baseFont").value);
  const pxValue = parseInt(document.querySelector("#pxValue").value);
  document.querySelector("#output").textContent = pxValue / baseFont;
}

document.querySelector("#convert").onclick = convert;
```

```html
<label>base font<input id="baseFont" type="number" value="16"/></label>
<label>px value<input id="pxValue" type="number" value="24"/></label>
<button id="convert" type="button">convert</button>
<br>
output <span id="output">1.5</span>rem
```

[source](https://pixelsconverter.com/px-to-rem)

Comment: Thanks but what about for things like margin and padding? That's not font size..

Comment: Should work as well I think

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) and [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Comment: It was 2022, by then everyone should have been using `addEventListener`, not `onclick =`, especially for simple one-offs like this. Also, I don't see how this answers the question, other that providing a form so the user could enter every px value they have one by one and get the rem value to use instead...

Comment: @HereticMonkey `onclick` is fine for this small snippet

Comment: It's really not. People come to Stack Overflow for high quality answers. Answers which use lazy, legacy coding techniques are not high quality.